# Can an Egyptian national marry a Bulgarian national in Bulgaria while on a tourist visa?

Tags: tourist-visas, bulgaria, egyptian-citizens, weddings

I am a citizen of Egypt. Would I be allowed to get married in Bulgaria while visiting Bulgaria on a tourist visa? If it matters, my fiancée is Bulgarian.

Comment: It's off topic and you don't need to make a new account

Comment: @GayotFow what u mean that's off topic ?

Comment: Try this one http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I was tempted to vote it as off-topic, I think it can be salvaged with some editing, essentially, turning it into "Am I allowed to marry while travelling to Bulgaria on a tourist visa".  This would be on-topic here, I believe. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **yes you can**, but it does matter that your fiancee is Bulgarian.

There is a [residency requirement](https://bulgaria.usembassy.gov/married4.html) for getting married in Bulgaria (but only one of you needs to be Bulgarian):

> Marriages in Bulgaria are subject to the residency requirement.  One
>   of the parties to the marriage should be either a citizen of Bulgaria
>   or domicile in the country.

Also, according to the Family Code in Bulgarian Law, you need to clear [Articles 6 and 7](http://kenarova.com/law/Family%20Code.pdf) to be eligible to marry. Article 6 mentions the residency requirement and Article 7 lists the prohibitions for contracting, but none of the prohibitions specifically exclude foreigners nor is there anything in the [Visa Type C](http://www.mfa.bg/uploads/files/VISA_C_en.pdf) conditions that forbids you from marrying while on a visit visa.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

People from my country often get married in Bulgaria even though both are non Bulgarian nationals.

[This website](http://www.lawyers-bulgaria.com/marriage-in-bulgaria) also shows that there should be no problem. Note that this also lists the documents you need to bring with you.

Comment: Is this your website ? This still doesn't answer if an Egyptian national can get married on a tourist visa though

Comment: @blackbird this isn't my website. Maybe [this](https://www.wikiprocedure.com/index.php/Bulgaria_-_Getting_Married) has better info?